# Python counter in Prolog

Tags: prolog

In Python you can do

```
>>> import from collections counter
>>> Counter(['a','b','b','c'])
>>> Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1})
```

Is there something similar in Prolog? Like so:

```
counter([a,b,b,c],S). 
S=[a/1,b/2,c/1].
```

This is my implementation:

```
counter([],List,Counts,Counts).

counter([H|T],List,Counts0,[H/N|Counts]):-
  findall(H, member(H,List), S),
  length(S,N),
  counter(T,List,Counts0,Counts).

counter(List,Counts):-
  list_to_set(List,Set),
  counter(Set,List,[],Counts).
```

It's rather verbose, so I wondered if there was a builtin predicate or a more terse implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no builtin predicate, here is another way to do that :

```
counter([X], [X/1]).

counter([H | T], R) :-
    counter(T, R1),
    (   select(H/V, R1, R2)
    ->  V1 is V+1,
        R = [H/V1 | R2]
    ;   R = [H/1 | R1]).
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @joel76's solution. I will add a few more variations on the theme.

*VARIATION I*

Here's another simple approach, which sorts the list first:

```
counter(L, C) :-
    msort(L, S),             % Use 'msort' instead of 'sort' to preserve dups
    counter(S, 1, C).
counter([X], A, [X-A]).
counter([X,X|T], A, C) :-
    A1 is A + 1,
    counter([X|T], A1, C).
counter([X,Y|T], A, [X-A|C]) :-
    X \= Y,
    counter([Y|T], 1, C).
```

Quick trial:

```
| ?- counter([a,b,b,c], S).

S = [a-1,b-2,c-1] ?

yes
```

This will fail on `counter([], C).` but you can simply include the clause `counter([], []).` if you want it to succeed. It doesn't maintain the initial order of appearance of the elements (it's unclear whether this is a requirement). This implementation is fairly efficient and is tail recursive, and it will work as long as the first argument is instantiated.

*VARIATION II*

This version will maintain order of appearance of elements, and it succeeds on `counter([], []).`. It's also tail recursive:

```
counter(L, C) :-
    length(L, N),
    counter(L, N, C).
counter([H|T], L, [H-C|CT]) :-
    delete(T, H, T1),          % Remove all the H's
    length(T1, L1),            % Length of list without the H's
    C is L - L1,               % Count is the difference in lengths
    counter(T1, L1, CT).       % Recursively do the sublist
counter([], _, []).
```

With some results:

```
| ?-  counter([a,b,a,a,b,c], L).

L = [a-3,b-2,c-1]

yes
| ?- counter([], L).

L = []

yes
```

*VARIATION III*

This one uses a helper which isn't tail recursive, but it preserves the original order of elements, is fairly concise, and I think more efficient.

```
counter([X|T], [X-C|CT]) :-
    remove_and_count(X, [X|T], C, L),  % Remove and count X from the list
    counter(L, CT).                    % Count remaining elements
counter([], []).

% Remove all (C) instances of X from L leaving R
remove_and_count(X, L, C, R) :-
    select(X, L, L1), !,               % Cut to prevent backtrack to other clause
    remove_and_count(X, L1, C1, R),
    C is C1 + 1.
remove_and_count(_, L, 0, L).
```

This implementation will work as long as the first argument to `counter` is instantiated.

---

*SIDEBAR*

In the above predicates, I used the `Element-Count` pattern rather than `Element/Count` since some Prolog interpreters, SWI in particular, offer a number of predicates that know how to operate on associative lists of `Key-Value` pairs (see [SWI library(pairs)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs) and ISO predicate [keysort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=keysort/2)).

Answer (score 1):

I also like @joel76 solution (and @mbratch suggestions, also). Here I'm just to note that library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)), if available, has a count aggregate operation, that can be used with the ISO builtin setof/3:

```
counter(L, Cs) :-
    setof(K-N, (member(K, L), aggregate(count, member(K, L), N)), Cs).
```

yields

```
?- counter([a,b,b,c], L).
L = [a-1, b-2, c-1].
```

If the selection operation was more complex, a nice way to avoid *textually* repeating the code could be

```
counter(L, Cs) :-
    P = member(K, L),
    setof(K-N, (P, aggregate(count, P, N)), Cs).
```

*edit*

Since I'm assuming library(aggregate) available, could be better to task it the set construction also:

```
counter(L, Cs) :-
    P = member(E,L), aggregate(set(E-C), (P, aggregate(count,P,C)), Cs).
```